# Problems about vertical center in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I think it's a stupid error but I don't understand.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

But my image is not centered.

I look on MDN and the image is centered
[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

My page :

[image]

Comment: You forgot to style the intermediate div (`.box div`), didn't you?

Comment: I don't understand "to style"
the CSS it is in flex.css

Comment: add height 100vh

Comment: A div is only as big as its contents.

Comment: with .box div the image is not centered

Comment: I'have delete le <div> around img but the error is still there

Comment: to see better what happens , add a background-color or a border/shadow  to your elements .... so you see where they stand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's all your code, you forgot the CSS:

```
.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Furthermore, try adding max vertical height as others have suggested.

```
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think adding height will solve your issue.

```
.box {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank, it's good but why on MDN there have not "height: 100vh"

Comment: but the centered fontion is "align-items: center" no ?!

Comment: @AdriDev The MDN example has `.box { height: 300px; }`.

Comment: o0 ok but 100vh is not perfect center, there have not number to perfect center

Comment: 100vh takes complete height of your viewport and align-items:center makes your content centered vertically .. I dont get it if its not perfect center?

Comment: Maybe it's just on my screen.
but there's the scrollbar that appears